# AngularJS: Variable not updating in scope

Tags: angularjs

I am using very similar code I have used many times but for some reason one of my variables has decided to not update in the scope and I have no idea why.

Here you can see I am binding to a variable 'UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved'

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" size="8" ng-model="UserGroupsSelectedToBeMovedBack">
    <option ng-repeat="ChosenUserGroup in Audit.UserGroups" value="{{ChosenUserGroup.Id}}">{{ChosenUserGroup.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

So when anything is selected that variable will be updated in the scope. Easy enough... But it doesn't update. $scope.UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved is always null unless i specify it in my controller.

If i write,

```
{{UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved}}
```

in my html I can see the value changing as I click. If i set the value of the variable in my controller it will be displayed in the html correctly as well as soon as the page loads. But it just won't update in the scope when the user clicks, despite the fact I can see it updating in the html. I can't make any sense of why this is happening.

**EDIT**

Got around this issue by changing my select by using ng-change like so,

```
<select class="form-control"
        size="8"
        multiple
        ng-model="UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved"
        ng-options="userGroup.Id as userGroup.Name for userGroup in AvailableUserGroups"
        ng-change="ChangeSelectedValueToMove(UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved)"></select>
```

Then in my controller having this method,

```
$scope.ChangeSelectedValueToMove = function (selectedIds) {
    $scope.UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved = selectedIds;
}
```

It's a horribly round about way of doing it, considering the original code i posted seems to work fine elsewhere in my project, but it works now.

Comment: Could you share us your data ? (To make a codepen)

Comment: How are you adding the controller to the html?

Comment: back is missing in variable {{UserGroupsSelectedToBeMoved}}

Comment: if i understood your question , i think you should ng-change=func_name(), when option values are changed

Comment: can you provide a js fiddle ?

Comment: In ng-model use like ng-model="container.parameter".

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late update. I just got this working using ng-change as shown in my edit above. Still not 100% sure why it was necessary to do it like that though.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

I strongly recommend that you do. What's happening to you is probably the scoping issues that stem from binding **directly** onto primitive variables (string, int, etc..).

It's therefore considered best practice to **always** place those under an object so you'll have `ng-model="MyContainer.MyParameter"` structure.

So basically, change that to use this practice, and read the article :)